# How to assess model fit for multilevel SEM (using Mplus)?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, fixed-effects-model, structural-equation-modeling, mplus

According to a preprint chapter by Sadikaj et al. (2019), the standard way to establish model fit for multilevel SEM is (1) develop a measurement model at each level if latent variables are included and assess fit at each level using Ryu & West (2009) procedure (2) estimate a fixed effects only model and evaluate model fit at each level (3) add random effects to test a theory about within-person processes (4) compare fit of fixed effects model with random effects model using either the likelihood ratio test or information criteria. Sadikaj et al.'s (2019) chapter can be found here >> https://psyarxiv.com/hwj9r/download/?format=pdf

I need help to modify an existing set of Mplus codes so that it tests a fixed effects only model. If you have knowledge on how to do so, I would greatly greatly appreciate your help! Please kindly reply to this and I would connect with you for further discussions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is an excellent question. The question of multilevel model fit is a hot topic and you are right that many people are following those 2009 recommendations. In brief, you can saturate the W or B levels of analysis separately and then build your model at the other level as you normally would for an SEM. However there are many issues to consider.

First, typical SEM measures of fit cannot be estimated when there is no logical saturated model. There is no single logical saturated model when parameters are allowed to vary across the sampled units of analysis, because this implies differences in the observed and population covariance matrix (and/or means). In other words, there is no single covariance matrix, and thus no single saturated model to generate fit information. This occurs in a variety of cases, including latent interaction models and multilevel models with random slopes or variances. These models imply parametric differences across the sampled units of analysis and therefore do not allow estimating typical fit indices. As noted by "The main problem with model fit evaluation for nonlinear MSEM is well-known from the evaluation of single-level nonlinear SEM: Model fit cannot be determined because a suitable saturated model does not exist (Klein and Schermelleh-Engel, 2010). For nonlinear SEM as well as for nonlinear MSEM the target model is not nested within the saturated model that is represented by the unstructured covariance matrix." (Schermelleh-Engel et al., 2014: 3).

There is also the fact that the B level usually has smaller variances than the W level and the B level always has fewer observations, so W model fit will dominate the global model fit indices. This must be considered when looking at MSEM model fit.